# How to publish page while using Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, landing-page

I am building a custom preference center in SFMC with SSJS that will pass the subscriber context into the landing page via the `microSiteUrl()` from an email. I am building and testing JUST the landing page portion. In my code I am using the `Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('xxxxxxxxxx)` to get the `Subscriber Key`, `JobID` and `BatchID`. I need these to log an unsub event.

When I go to publish (or even preview) the page I get an error. If I comment out the code, everything is fine. I know that *technically* the subscriber context isn't there because I'm not accessing the landing page via an email with `microSiteUrl()`. How can I get those 3 values (`subscriberID`, `JobID` and `BatchID`) and still publish the page?

This is my code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1");

    /*subscriber context */
    var subscriberKey = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('_subcriberkey');
    var batchid = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('BatchID'); 
    var jobid = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('JobID');`
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use from either of the two options below to retrieve the `_subscriberKey` :

**Core Function:**

```
var SubscriberKey = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberKey");
```

**Platform Function:**

```
var SubscriberKey = Platform.Recipient.GetAttributeValue("_subscriberKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually set those variables in AMPscript, which still allows me to save the page even though there aren't any values.

```
%%[
SET @subscriberKey = _subscriberkey
SET @emailAddress = emailaddr 
SET @jobID = jobid 
SET @listID = listid 
SET @batchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID 
]%%
```

Then simple refer to them in SSJS using the following:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1")
    var emailFields = {
        //NOTE: Retrieving AMPscript variables into SSJS if coming from email.
        subKey: Variable.GetValue("@subscriberKey"),
        emailAddress: Variable.GetValue("@emailAddress"),
        jobID: Variable.GetValue("@jobID"),
        listID: Variable.GetValue("@listID"),
        batchID: Variable.GetValue("@batchID")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much. I will give that a shot.

Comment: I finally got a chance to implement and the landing page will still NOT publish. This is the code. Am I missing something?

 `<!-- AMPScipt to retrieve subscriber context-->
%%[
 SET @subscriberKey = _subscriberkey
 SET @jobID = jobid 
 SET @batchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID 
]%%
<script runat="server">
 Platform.Load("core","1");
                                             
  /*retrieve values set in AMPscript */
   var subKey = Variable.GetValue("@subscriberKey");
   var batch = Variable.GetValue("@batchID");
   var job, = Attribute.getValue('@jobID');
</script>`

Comment: Try removing the comma from "var job, = Attribute.getValue('@jobID')"