# How to pass subscriber info to SSJS in landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, landing-page

I am building a custom preference center in SFMC with SSJS that will pass the subscriber context into the landing page via the `microSiteUrl()` from an email. I am building out and testing JUST the landing page portion. I am having an issue publishing the page - it will error out when I have the following code active. If I comment the code out, the page will publish. I NEED the information in order to run the `logUnsubscribeEvent`. I was given the [following](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213820/how-to-publish-page-while-using-platform-variable-getattributevalue) as a way to write my code. It still doesn't work. The page will not publish - I just get the spinner. What am I missing. This is my code:

```
<!-- AMPScipt to retrieve subscriber context from microSiteUrl() -->
%%[

     SET @subscriberKey = _subscriberkey
     SET @jobID = jobid 
     SET @batchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID 
]%% 
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");

    /* declare variables */

    /*retrieve values set in AMPscript */
    var subKey = Variable.GetValue("@subscriberKey");
    var batch = Variable.GetValue("@batchID");
    var job = Attribute.getValue('@jobID');

</script>
```

it's not showing up in my code above .. but SSJS IS wrapped in opening and closing script `runat="server"` tags

Answer (score 4):

No need to do the AMPscript block first.

The SSJS has the same context as the AMPscript block.  You can just retrieve them directly with `Attribute.GetValue()`:

```
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core","1");
    var subKey = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");
    var batch = Attribute.GetValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID");
    var job = Attribute.GetValue('jobid');

</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this and the page will not publish. It will just continue to get the spinner. If I comment out the section with `Attribute.GetValue()` the page publishes fine. Any other thoughts???

Comment: -tried it again and it worked. I could publish!!!! Thank you so much @Adam